# Installing Javascript in symfony2

Tags: javascript, symfony, installation

Hi Stackoverflow people.

Im trying to use a javascript graph in a test twig view. This is the view:

```
    <h1>test</h1>
{% javascripts '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
  <script src="{{ asset_url }}"  type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {

  title:{
    text: "Fruits"              
  },
  data: [//array of dataSeries              
    { //dataSeries object

     /*** Change type "column" to "bar", "area", "line" or "pie"***/
     type: "column",
     dataPoints: [
     { label: "banana", y: 18 },
     { label: "orange", y: 29 },
     { label: "apple", y: 40 },                                    
     { label: "mango", y: 34 },
     { label: "grape", y: 24 }
     ]
   }
   ]
 });

chart.render();
  }


     </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
      {% endjavascripts %}

      <body>
      <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
      </div>
    </body>
```

So the problem is that the javascript library is not installed because it returns to me this error message:

> An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("You must add PreditBundle to the assetic.bundle config to use the {% javascripts %} tag in PreditBundle:Default:test.html.twig.") in "PreditBundle:Default:test.html.twig".

Things I've tryed:

-Follow step by step the page "how to use assetic for asset management
-Use the console comands : assets:install and assetic:dump

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your bundle in config.yml.

```
assetic:
    bundle: [ PreditBundle ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined the `scr` attribute for a `script` element and than use inline javascript code?
Do either:

```
<script src="..."></script>
```

or:

```
<script> alert(123); </script>
```

Also the `{% javascript %}` block of twig is for rendering multiple javascript assets in one step. Not for inline *and* remote javascript files. Use it like this:

**your-template.html.twig**:

```
{% javascript '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"  type="text/javascript">
{% javascript %}
<script>

    window.onload = function () {
    // ...

</script>
```

Also you need to add your bundle in config.yml as @oumlaote already stated.